# Как сократить длину href?

Tags: javascript

Есть код

```
(function (d) {
    d.each(["backgroundColor", "borderBottomColor", "borderLeftColor", "borderRightColor", "borderTopColor", "color", "outlineColor"], function (f, e) {
        d.fx.step[e] = function (g) {
            if (!g.colorInit) {
                g.start = c(g.elem, e);
                g.end = b(g.end);
                g.colorInit = true
            }
            g.elem.style[e] = "rgb(" + [Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((g.pos * (g.end[0] - g.start[0])) + g.start[0]), 255), 0), Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((g.pos * (g.end[1] - g.start[1])) + g.start[1]), 255), 0), Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((g.pos * (g.end[2] - g.start[2])) + g.start[2]), 255), 0)].join(",") + ")"
        }
    });

    function b(f) {
        var e;
        if (f && f.constructor == Array && f.length == 3) {
            return f
        }
        if (e = /rgb\(\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*\)/.exec(f)) {
            return [parseInt(e[1]), parseInt(e[2]), parseInt(e[3])]
        }
        if (e = /rgb\(\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*,\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*,\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*\)/.exec(f)) {
            return [parseFloat(e[1]) * 2.55, parseFloat(e[2]) * 2.55, parseFloat(e[3]) * 2.55]
        }
        if (e = /#([a-fA-F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/.exec(f)) {
            return [parseInt(e[1], 16), parseInt(e[2], 16), parseInt(e[3], 16)]
        }
        if (e = /#([a-fA-F0-9])([a-fA-F0-9])([a-fA-F0-9])/.exec(f)) {
            return [parseInt(e[1] + e[1], 16), parseInt(e[2] + e[2], 16), parseInt(e[3] + e[3], 16)]
        }
        if (e = /rgba\(0, 0, 0, 0\)/.exec(f)) {
            return a.transparent
        }
        return a[d.trim(f).toLowerCase()]
    }
    function c(g, e) {
        var f;
        do {
            f = d.css(g, e);
            if (f != "" && f != "transparent" || d.nodeName(g, "body")) {
                break
            }
            e = "backgroundColor"
        } while (g = g.parentNode);
        return b(f)
    }
})(jQuery);




oldest = 0;

function search(id, mode_raw, token, channel, count, stop, color) {
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://slack.com/api/channels.history",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
    "token": token,
    "channel": channel,
    "inclusive": true,
    "count": count,
    "oldest": oldest
    },
    success: function (data) {  

        tester = ''; // чтобы не повторялись билеты
        for (var i=0; i < data.messages.length; i++)
        {   
            if(data.messages[i].ts == oldest) continue; // повторы уберем
            if(data.messages[i].attachments[0].title_link == tester) continue;
            tester = data.messages[i].attachments[0].title_link;



        if (data.messages[i].bot_id){

            switch (mode_raw) {

            case 0:
            if (data.messages[i].text.length !== 0){

                $(id).html('<tr><td colspan="8">Возможно у Вас установлен mode raw на канале в slack. Поставьте значение <b>mode_raw = 1</b></td></tr>');

            break;
            }
                //var callback_id = data.messages[i].attachments["0"].callback_id; // ticket_MOW-ROV
                var fallback = data.messages[i].attachments["0"].fallback; // Аномальный билет. Москва — Ростов-на-Дону. В одну сторону: 10.04 за 1 732 ?
                var text = data.messages[i].attachments["0"].text.match(/~(.*?)\u{20BD}~.*\*(.*?)\u{20BD}\*/u); // берем для получения цен
                var title = data.messages[i].attachments["0"].title; // Москва (Россия) — Ростов-на-Дону (Россия)
                var info = data.messages[i].attachments["0"].footer; // 1 пересадка в Стамбуле 2 часа, Turkish Airlines
                var title_link = '<a style="padding:3px;text-decoration:none;background: #00a4f7;box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px #000000;color: #fff;" title="Посмотреть авиабилет" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="' + data.messages[i].attachments["0"].title_link + '";return false">Перейти</a>'; // ссылка
                var price_old = text[1].replace(/\s/g, '');  // старая цена
                var price_new = text[2].replace(/\s/g, '');  // новая цена
                var percentage = price_old - price_new;
                //console.log(text);
                var percentage = ((percentage * 100) / price_old).toFixed()+'%'; // скидка
                var From = title.match(/(.*) \—/)[1];
                var To = title.match(/\— (.*?)\)/)[1]+')';

                if (fallback.indexOf("Туда") !== -1){
                        var datew = fallback.match(/Туда: (.*?)\,.*обратно: (.*?) за/);
                        var datew = datew[1] + ' - ' + datew[2];
                        var there = 'Туда: ' + info.match(/Туда (.*?)\n/)[1];
                        var back = ' - Обратно: ' + info.match(/Обратно: (.*)/)[1];
                        } else {
                        var datew = fallback.match(/сторону: (.*?) за/);
                        var datew = datew[1] + ' - в одну сторону';
                        var there = '';
                        var back = '';

                }
                    var main_tpl = '<tr class="trhover" style="background: #68c2fe;">'
                    +'<td style="border-left:1px solid #ffffff;background:  rgba(145, 221, 255, 0.3);color:black;padding: 15px;font-size: 17px;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;" data-label="Откуда">' + From + '</td>'
                    +'<td style="border-left:1px solid #ffffff;background:  rgba(145, 221, 255, 0.3);color:black;padding: 15px;font-size: 17px;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;" data-label="Куда">' + To + '</td>'
                    +'<td style="border-left:1px solid #ffffff;background:  rgba(145, 221, 255, 0.3);color:black;padding: 15px;font-size: 17px;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;" data-label="Дата">' + datew + '</td>'
                    +'<td style="border-left:1px solid #ffffff;background:rgba(249, 145, 255, 0.3);color:black;padding: 15px;font-size: 17px;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;" data-label="Старая цена">' + price_old + '</td>'
                    +'<td style="border-left:1px solid #ffffff;background:  rgba(145, 221, 255, 0.3);color:black;padding: 15px;font-size: 17px;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;" data-label="Новая цена">' + price_new + '</td>'
                    +'<td style="border-left:1px solid #ffffff;background:  rgba(145, 221, 255, 0.3);color:black;padding: 15px;font-size: 17px;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;" data-label="Скидка">' + percentage + '</td>'
                    +'<td style="border-left:1px solid #ffffff;background:  rgba(145, 221, 255, 0.3);color:black;padding: 15px;font-size: 17px;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;">' + title_link + '</td>'
                    +'</tr>';

            break;
            case 1:

            if (data.messages[i].text.length == 0) {

            $(id).html('<tr><td colspan="8">Возможно у Вас не установлен mode raw на канале в slack. Поставьте значение <b>mode_raw = 0</b></td></tr>');

            break;
            }
                if (data.messages[i].text.indexOf('<http') != -1){

                var text = data.messages[i].text.match(/(.*?)\</)[1]; // для получения информации
                var From = text.match(/(.*) \—/)[1]; // откуда
                var To = text.match(/\— (.*?)\./)[1]; // куда

                if (text.indexOf("Туда") !== -1){
                var datew = text.match(/Туда: (.*?)\,.*обратно: (.*?) за/);
                var datew = datew[1] + ' - ' + datew[2]; // 06.09 - 13.09
                } else {
                var datew = text.match(/сторону: (.*?) за/);
                var datew = datew[1] + ' - В одну сторону'; // 12.07 - В одну сторону
                }
                var price = text.match(/за (.*?)\u{20BD}/u)[1] + '&#8381;'; // цена
                var ts_id = data.messages[i].ts;
                var link = data.messages[i].text.match(/\<(.*?)\>/)[1];
                var href = '<a class="link" title="Посмотреть авиабилет ' + From + ' ' + To + ' ' + there + back + '" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="/' + ts_id + '" onclick="window.open(\''+ link +'\');return false">Перейти</a>'; // ссылка


                var main_tpl = '<tr class="trhover" style="background: #68c2fe;color: white;">'
                +'<td>' + From + '</td>'
                +'<td>' + To + '</td>'
                +'<td>' + datew + '</td>'
                +'<td>' + price + '</td>'
                +'<td>' + href + '</td>'
                +'</tr>';

                } else {
                    var main_tpl = '<tr><td colspan="8">' + data.messages[i].text + '</td></tr>';
                }

            break;
            default:

                $(id).html('<tr><td colspan="8">Укажите <b>mode_raw = 0 или 1</b> ?\_(?)_/?</td></tr>');

            break;


            }


        } else {
        var main_tpl = '<tr><td colspan="8">' + data.messages[i].text + '</td></tr>';
        }


        $(main_tpl).prependTo(id).animate({ // выводим значения в id="auto_price"
        backgroundColor: color
        }, 2100); 


        } // конец for

        if ($(id + " tr").length > stop)
        $(id + " tr").slice(stop, $(id + " tr").length).remove();

        if (data.messages[0].ts){
            oldest = data.messages[0].ts;
        }
    }, // конец success

    error: function () {
    console.log("Ошибка получения сообщений");
    }

});
}
```

Появляется вот такая таблица
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо путь ссылки в кнопке "Перейти" сократить на 26 символов сначала. Не получается. Помогите пожалуйста.

Кнопка "перейти" ведет на путь `https://hydra.aviasales.ru//MOW2411BUD28111?t=W615430575001543059600000155VKOBUD15433845001543401000000155BUDVKO_9fcbb43ccb19a3f784b0127aa9daa838_5623&expected_price=5623&expected_price_uuid=dbe0bf72-89db-487e-9370-e10aa3c9d85e&expected_price_source=medon&medon_route_id=Z1mxD_YPnM&marker=87111.medon&utm_campaign=medon&utm_source=slack&utm_medium=social&utm_content=%D0%90%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%23aviasales`

Мне необходимо чтобы путь выглядел вот так `//MOW2411BUD28111?t=W615430575001543059600000155VKOBUD15433845001543401000000155BUDVKO_9fcbb43ccb19a3f784b0127aa9daa838_5623&expected_price=5623&expected_price_uuid=dbe0bf72-89db-487e-9370-e10aa3c9d85e&expected_price_source=medon&medon_route_id=Z1mxD_YPnM&marker=87111.medon&utm_campaign=medon&utm_source=slack&utm_medium=social&utm_content=%D0%90%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%23aviasales`

Comment: `ts_id` -> `ts_id.slice(0, 25)` ... что значит "сократить"? Если вам нужна короткая ссылка, то это не к js, нужно ассоциацию роутов делать.

Comment: Вы удалите весь код из ответа, и приведите примеры "какие ссылки есть" => "что хотите". Нафига кому-то созерцать этот код, когда задача конкретная?

Comment: @MedvedevDev Вот такого плана ссылки https://hydra.aviasales.ru//MOW3007PFO09081?t=S715329502001532964300000235DMEPFO15338316001533845700000235PFODME_a6141fb378288db8325b10d9f7ce559e_13363&expected_price=13363&expected_price_uuid=04eb4957-1acf-4dff-bf00-7da8b841d4c5&expected_price_source=medon&medon_route_id=IzDpRhY1Os&marker=87111.medon&utm_campaign=medon&utm_source=slack&utm_medium=social&utm_content=%D0%90%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%23aviasales

Comment: Вот эта строка var href = '<a class="link" title="Посмотреть авиабилет ' + From + ' ' + To + ' ' + there + back + '" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="/' + ts_id + '" onclick="window.open(\''+ link +'\');return false">Перейти</a>'; // ссылка

Comment: с чем связана потребность сокращать ссылки?

Comment: @MedvedevDev Данные беруться по Апи, необходимо что-бы я смог заменить  hydra.aviasales.ru на свой поддомен

Comment: При чем тут сокращение? Вам надо домен обрезать, оставить только относительный путь ....Замените `ts_id` на `ts_id.slice(26)`

Comment: @Arcadiy https://tproger.ru/explain/xyproblem/

Comment: @Arcadiy в вопросе напишите - "что есть" => "что хотите" несколько примеров, тут не форум предсказателей, тут нужна конкретика в вопросах

Comment: @MedvedevDev Не сработало

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр дополнил вопрос в самом низу

Comment: @MedvedevDev Спасибо, сработало, нужно было только не ts заменить, а title_link   Оформите ответом, я приму его. Спасибо